# How to use read-only Expression Body Properties with x:Bind in UWP apps

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I would like to declare read-only real-time properties using expression body:

```
    public string RealTimeData => RetrievLiveData(Duration);
```

Use x:Bind to update UI controls:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="LiveDataCtrl" Text="{x:Bind RealTimeData, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The binding updates when the page loads, but I can't figure out a way to update the binding from the page (e.g., from a button click).

Being it's not dependency property and not backed by INPC, I have been looking for ways to trigger the binding manually.

I've tried GetBindingExpression with no luck:

```
    LiveDataCtrl.GetBindingExpression(WhatGoesHere?);
```

Comment: Hi, are you using MVVM? If so, could you provide your ViewModel code?

Comment: Did you try Raising a `PropertyChanged` notification that we usually do in MVVM?

Comment: This is in a UserControl using code-behind. I am intentionally not using INPC or DP. Just trying a different way to better understand binding internals and new C# features. Just need to figure out how to replicate the steps executed when the page is loaded -- which work.

Comment: If someone knows how to get GetBindingExpression() to work that should allow me to call UpdateTarget() -- problem solved. I'm just not sure what needs to be passed in to GetBindingExpression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetBindingExpression` method returns the [BindingExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.bindingexpression) object which contains information about a single instance of a [Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding), not `x:Bind`.

There's no bindingexpression with `x:Bind`. But in your case, you could call `this.Bindings.Update();` to force it to update source.

For example:

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string RealTimeData => RetrievLiveData();
    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string RetrievLiveData()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Bindings.Update();
    }
}
```